# path to folder in XML in WAR-container

Tags: xml, maven, path, war

i have a java-servlet project which deploys via Maven to a .war-file. this runs in the tomcat servlet container. since i am using Wordnet (to be precise i use this API: http://extjwnl.sourceforge.net/) i have a so called file_properties.xml file which holds a value for the "dictionary_path". this value should hold the path to the stored dictionaries. when i tested on my local machine the following value - of course - worked: "C:\Users\XY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\project-name\src\main\resources\dict\"

after deployment to a war-file and running in tomcat this path of course does not work anymore. how can i enter the value in the XML correctly? the target folder lies in the war-file in the "\WEB-INF\classes" folder.

the xml looks like this right now:
`<param name="dictionary_path" value="C:\Users\username\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectname\src\main\resources\dict\"/>`

SOLUTION:
we now solved this with a workaround: we do not need the XML file anymore. instead we instantiate the dictionary by providing the path:

```
String dictPath = WordNetDictionary.class.getResource("/dict").toExternalForm();
//trim dictPath here depending on the OS
this.dictionary = Dictionary.getFileBackedInstance(dictPath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
we now solved this with a workaround: we do not need the XML file anymore. instead we instantiate the dictionary by providing the path:

```
String dictPath = WordNetDictionary.class.getResource("/dict").toExternalForm();
//trim dictPath here depending on the OS
this.dictionary = Dictionary.getFileBackedInstance(dictPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your framework appears to require a file, and you're packaging as a .war, there's your immediate problem.

I would perhaps take the following approach. Package your properties file in your .war. You can then use [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). That will find the properties file packaged with your classes. Read it, and *write it to a nominated directory*. That directory should match that in your XML configuration. You can then instantiate your framework with your given config, and that path would point to a directory in which you've written the file.

Comment: "You should use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()"
in the XML? i need the correct path in the XML.
the XML looks like this right now:
`<param name="dictionary_path" value="C:\Users\username\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectname\src\main\resources\dict\"/>` and i think i cant use `getResourceAsStream()` in the XML, can i?

Comment: I didn't fully appreciate the details of this, and I've amended the answer appropriately